# Round lineend geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to make round lineends for `geom_smooth`? For there is no lineend argument, `geom_smooth(lineend = "round")` obviously fails. I also tried in vain:

```
update_geom_defaults("smooth", list(lineend = "round"))
```

So either there is some simple option I am not aware of or lineend is hard coded and thus one needs to come up with a custom `geom_smooth` function which I don't know how to.

Don't think it needs a MRE, but:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_smooth(size = 4)  # increase size to discern lineends
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved using `stat_smooth`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + stat_smooth(size = 4, geom = "line", lineend = "round", color = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!  Just ran into this and raised an issue for the developers: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4581.